# JavaFx: object property adapter

Tags: java, javafx

For DTO I use POJO. So to make bidirectional binding I create adapter. The problem I don't know how to use ObjectProperty listenet. So I have the DTO - I inform JavaFx properties via listener:

```
public class Temp{
   private BigDecimal weight;
   private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
   public Temp() {
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
   }
   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
   public BigDecimal getWeight() {
     return weight;
   }
   public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
     BigDecimal pv = this.weight;
    this.weight = weight;
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("weight", pv, weight);
   }
}
```

I have the following adapter:

```
public class TempAdapter {
    private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> weightProperty;
    public TempAdapter(Temp temp) {
        try {
            weightProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<BigDecimal>().bean(temp).name("weight").build();
            weightProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends BigDecimal> ov, BigDecimal t, BigDecimal t1) {
           // WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE????????????????
                }
            });
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
 public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> getWeightProperty() {
    return weightProperty;
}
```

But I can't understand what I should write in listener for bidirectional(!) binding. Please, help.

Comment: Should `task` be `temp`?

Comment: @James_D Yes, I corrected the error.

Comment: I don't think you need that listener at all... it should already be handled by the `JavaBeanObjectProperty`. Doesn't it work? (If not, can you post some test code?)

Comment: @James_D Uff, I cant test as I don't know how to bind it to TextField myTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getWeightProperty(),new NumberStringConverter())? How to bind?

Comment: You need to implement a `StringConverter<BigDecimal>`

Comment: @James_D I did this way:myTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(adapter.getWeightProperty(),new BigDecimalStringConverter()); And it worked. But If I had for example Date? Or my custom object. What I should do in listener? Can you show custom listener for BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that listener at all; it just works:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.adapter.JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;


public class BigDecimalBindingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp temp = new Temp();
        temp.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> 
                System.out.printf("temp changed from %s to %s %n", evt.getOldValue(), evt.getNewValue()));

        temp.setWeight(BigDecimal.ZERO);
        TempAdapter adapter = new TempAdapter(temp);
        adapter.weightProperty.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            System.out.printf("adapter changed from %s to %s%n", oldValue, newValue));

        StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty();

        text.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
                System.out.printf("text changed from %s to %s%n", oldValue, newValue));

        text.bindBidirectional(adapter.getWeightProperty(), new StringConverter<BigDecimal>(){

            @Override
            public String toString(BigDecimal object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public BigDecimal fromString(String string) {
                return new BigDecimal(string);
            }

        });



        System.out.println("Setting temp");
        temp.setWeight(new BigDecimal(2));

        System.out.println("Setting text");
        text.set("3.0");
    }

    public static class Temp{
        private BigDecimal weight;
        private final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
        public Temp() {
             this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        }
        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
             propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        }
        public BigDecimal getWeight() {
          return weight;
        }
        public void setWeight(BigDecimal weight) {
          BigDecimal pv = this.weight;
         this.weight = weight;
         propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("weight", pv, weight);
        }
     }

    public static class TempAdapter {
        private ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> weightProperty;

        public TempAdapter(Temp temp) {
            try {
                weightProperty = new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<BigDecimal>()
                        .bean(temp).name("weight").build();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                        null, ex);
            }
        }

        public ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> getWeightProperty() {
            return weightProperty;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't understand how T from ObjectProperty<T> converts to string and back, but it happens in StringConverter.

Comment: Could you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713639/javafx-binding-does-beanpathadapter-work ?